# Endpoint name matchness

Tags: wcf

I have an app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WsIGetHeaders" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TcpIGetHeaders" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/DemoService/HeaderService/"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsIGetHeaders"
            contract="DemoService.IGetHeaders" name="WsIGetHeaders">
        </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/DemoService/HeaderService/"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpIGetHeaders"
          contract="DemoService.IGetHeaders" name="TcpIGetHeaders">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

We know binding name must match bindingConfiguration, but how about name of the endpoint in client section. I used the black pen to circle it. The red ones match each other. Any msdn for it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endpoint name is used in client side configuration to match later in the code when creating client instance. Some information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535060%28v=office.14%29.aspx). 
Sample of constructing service client proxy object as each proxy class derived from ClientBase which has approprite [ctor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms574925.aspx):

```
 client = new ServiceClient(useSecure ? "SecureEndpoint" : "defaultEndpoint");
```